# C# model for nested properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I need to make API request to CloudFlare to purge cache of individual files.

Can someone please guide how to represent the below as C# model class.

```
files: [
        "http://www.example.com/css/styles.css",
        {
          "url": "http://www.example.com/cat_picture.jpg",
          "headers": {
            "Origin": "cloudflare.com",
            "CF-IPCountry": "US",
            "CF-Device-Type": "desktop"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: The JSON you put is invalid.

Comment: Its mentioned in their API documentation https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-individual-files-by-url

Comment: @NaveedAhmed meh, I think we can imagine the outer braces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using classes (maybe you could use better class names then mine :) ):

```
class Root
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "files")]
    public List<object> Files { get; set; } = new List<object>();
}

class UrlContainer
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "headers")]
    public Headers Headers { get; set; }
}

class Headers
{
    public string Origin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CF-IPCountry")]
    public string CfIpCountry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CF-Device-Type")]
    public string CfDeviceType { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var root = new Root();

// Add a simple url string
root.Files.Add("http://www.example.com/css/styles.css");

var urlContainer = new UrlContainer() {
    Url = "http://www.example.com/cat_picture.jpg",
    Headers = new Headers()
    {
        Origin = "cloudflare.com",
        CfIpCountry = "US",
        CfDeviceType = "desktop"
    }
};

// Adding url with headers
root.Files.Add(urlContainer);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
```

**Note:** I'm using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 3):

```
    var obj = new
    {
        files = new object[]
        {
            "http://www.example.com/css/styles.css",
            new
            {
                url = "http://www.example.com/cat_picture.jpg",
                headers = new Dictionary<string,string>
                {
                    { "Origin", "cloudflare.com" },
                    { "CF-IPCountry","US" },
                    { "CF-Device-Type", "desktop"}
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

The dictionary is there because of the awkward property names like `CF-IPCountry` which make it not possible to use an anonymous type.

To show it working:

```
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
```

gives:

```
{
  "files": [
    "http://www.example.com/css/styles.css",
    {
      "url": "http://www.example.com/cat_picture.jpg",
      "headers": {
        "Origin": "cloudflare.com",
        "CF-IPCountry": "US",
        "CF-Device-Type": "desktop"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Edit; that's not quite right - the dictionary didn't work, but I don't have time to fix it.